# Fragments won't change on Android application

Tags: android, android-fragments

Respected programmers of stack overflow,
I am very new to the world of programming and am actually trying to build an app to help my fellow medical students.

In my app I can't seem to be able to change fragments after pressing buttons on the navigation bar. Only a single fragment loads at first (home fragment) and the rest do not change at all.
Since I am new to the programming world it may just be a small mistake on my part, but I do hope you all can guide me.

Here is my MainActivity java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bnView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bnView=findViewById(R.id.bnView);
        bnView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id=item.getItemId();
                if (id==R.id.home) {
                    loadfrag(new Homefragment(), true);
                }else if(id==R.id.subject_based) {
                    loadfrag(new subjectfragment(), false);
                }else if(id==R.id.about) {
                    loadfrag(new aboutfragment(), false);
                }else if(id==R.id.exam) {
                    loadfrag(new examfragment(), false);
                }else {
                    loadfrag(new paperfragment(), false);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        bnView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
    }
    public void loadfrag(Fragment fragment, boolean flag){
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();
        if (flag)
            ft.add(R.id.container,fragment);
        else
            ft.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

My main activity xml file is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/goojasto"
    tools:context="com.cringyprithak.mcqrunch_3.MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#EFD115"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My menu is as follows

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/subject_based"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sub"
        android:title="Subject-wise"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/paper"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_paper"
        android:title="Paper-wise"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exam"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exam"
        android:title="Exam Practice"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:title="About Me"/>


</menu>
```

and an example of the coding in my fragments would be

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class aboutfragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homefragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I have been trying all day to make a bottom navigation bar and have fragments switch according to the buttons in the navigation bar but I haven't been able to.
I've watched countless videos and tried anything I could find. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine in general. It is the proper way to switch between **Fragment** by using **BottomNavigationBar**.

Just a small change for following function. You can directly use `replace()` when switching between **Fragment**:

```java
    // Removed the boolean flag and use replace() directly
    public void loadfrag(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        // Can remove the add() function and just use replace()
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

So I guess the problem you encounter is when you try to load the view to your `Fragment`.

For your `aboutfragment`, you are trying to load `R.layout.fragment_homefragment`. And from the naming seems that it is a `HomeFragment` layout rather than your `aboutfragment` layout. You should have a your `aboutfragment` layout there:

```java
public class aboutfragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Should replace R.layout.fragment_homefragment with your aboutfragment layout
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homefragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

And for better practice, please follow [Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) when you are creating functions or classes.

For example:

- `Homefragment` should be in `HomeFragment`
- `aboutfragment` should be in `AboutFragment`

Comment: Thank you so much @Enowneb
I deleted all the previous fragments and used proper naming conventions on the new ones.
I also followed what you said about the final function loadfrag and now everything seems to be working well.
well lack of "reputation" wont let me upvote your post, but I do appreciate your help a lot. 
Thank you.